# Is there a more efficient way to write this repetition in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Looking for a way to make this sleeker and more efficient. I think the best way to do that would to be putting the conversation in a loop, but I honestly have no idea how to do that. I'm a hobbyist who just tinkers to learn.

```
@commands.command()
async def start_conversation(self, ctx): 
    start_chat_log = '''The following is a conversation with an AI assistant named Shem-Ha. Shem-Ha acts like an arrogant goddess.
    Human: Hello. Who are you? 
    AI: I am Shem-Ha. What do you want human? 
    '''

    def check(message: discord.Message):
        return message.channel == ctx.channel and message.author == ctx.author

    def ask(question, chat_log=None):
        if chat_log is None:
            chat_log = start_chat_log
        
        prompt = f'{chat_log}Human: {question}\nAI:'
        response = completion.create(
            prompt=prompt, 
            engine="davinci", 
            stop=['\n'], 
            temperature = 0.8, 
            top_p = 1, 
            frequency_penalty = 1, 
            presence_penalty = 1,
            best_of = 1,
            max_tokens=128
            )
        answer = response.choices[0].text.strip()
        return answer

    def append_interaction_to_chat_log(question, answer, chat_log=None):
        if chat_log is None:
            chat_log = start_chat_log
        return f'{chat_log}Human: {question}\nAI: {answer}\n'

    await ctx.send(f'I am Shem-Ha. What do you want human? ')

    r1 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    answer = ask(r1.content)
    await ctx.send(answer)
    chat_log = append_interaction_to_chat_log(r1.content, answer)

    r2 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    answer = ask(r2.content)
    await ctx.send(answer)
    chat_log = append_interaction_to_chat_log(r2.content, answer)

    r3 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    answer = ask(r3.content)
    await ctx.send(answer)
    chat_log = append_interaction_to_chat_log(r3.content, answer)
    
    await ctx.send(f'**conversation end**')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pop it into a for loop as so:

```py
for _ in range(3):
    r = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    answer = ask(r.content)
    await ctx.send(answer)
    chat_log = append_interaction_to_chat_log(r.content, answer)
```

This will run it 3 times